# Is it possible to define own literals in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, literals

For arbitrary-precision floating point decimal arithmetic in Ruby we can use the library `BigDecimal`. Unfortunately, compared to floats every explicitly given `BigDecimal` needs a lot of typing:

```
bd = BigDecimal("42.0")
# vs.
fl = 42.0
```

**Is is possible to define own literals in Ruby?**

So that for example the `BigDecimal` from above could be expressed like:

```
bd = 42°0
```

Or at least:

```
bd = %b(42.0)
```

Comment: Saves a little bit of typing: `BD = BigDecimal`. Gets you close to `%b`, with same amount of typing.

Comment: @Casper You mean `alias BD BigDecimal`?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, but I just realized you need the quotes for floats, so it's not the same as `%b` would be. Still a bit clunky, just shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ruby does not allow user-defined literals, overloading of literals, or any other similar thing.

Ruby *does* allow defining operator methods for existing operators, but not the definition of new operators, so even treating

```
42°0
```

as a binary operator `°` will not work.

The closest you can get would be monkey-patching a `°` method on `Integer`:

```
class Integer
  def °(decimal_part)
    BigDecimal("#{self}.#{decimal_part}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx. Smart solution. So, the closest we get with this solution is `42.° 0`.

Comment: @Dorian: Ruby allows you to leave out the parentheses around an argument list. I am surprised that you have never seen it used, e.g. it is quite common to use `puts "Hello"` instead of `puts("Hello")`, `require "bigdecimal"` instead of `require("bigdecimal")`, `attr_accessor :foo` instead of `attr_accessor(:foo)`, or `include Foo` instead of `include(Foo)`. In all of these cases it is, in fact, not just merely common, it is *idiomatic*.

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

```
def b(number)
  BigDecimal(number)
end
```

Then `b(42.0)` would work, pretty close to `%b(42.0)`

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Because `b(42.0)` already imposes the loss of precision. `b("42.0")` would work. But this is no more so close to `%b(42.0)`.